# NSWindowController problem

Tags: cocoa

I created a NSWindowController(.m.h) in a cocoa project.
I set the outlet of the NSWindowController as the window(NSWindow) in MainMenu.xib,

I found that the functions in NSWindowController.m below

```
- (BOOL)isWindowLoaded;
- (void)windowWillLoad;
- (void)windowDidLoad;
- (id)initWithWindow:(NSWindow*)window;
```

only

```
- (id)initWithWindow:(NSWindow*)window;
```

was triggered, and the value of the parameter window is 0x0.

I do not what caused this happen.

Welcome any comment.

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set NSWindow's `delegate` connection to point to your controller, otherwise it won't receive those events.

Comment: I have did just as you said. - (id)initWithWindow:(NSWindow*)window;
was triggered several times, but other functions above are not triggered as same as before.